# how to add combobox items in listbox or listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, listbox

I want to know what control to be use on my project is it Listview or listbox???.  I have a comboBox control on my project what I want to do is when I selected 1 item on my combobox it will automatically add on listbox or listview and when I selected more than 1 item I want to add it on listbox or listview on newline...

Is it simple, please help me to do that in listbox or listview..thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Listbox > Is for viewing too but user can select it
Listview > Is for viewing only, user cannot select also it viewing by five view directly cause it's for viewing only
```

If your project wanted the list to be viewing from what have been select by Combobox, then you just pick List View, but if you want for viewing also user can select it, better use listbox, so it's up to you.
Also you can know how the Tools work by focus your mouse cursor to the tool, then it will pop up an tooltip that write what the tool for.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ListView1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
    End Sub
```

That is the code to viewing in listview for what you select in combobox

For clearing all the item in the Listview or listbox, just write to your form_load

```
Listview.items.clear
```

Why i said in form load, cause the list just for viewing, of course every time the form begin to run, it will need blank list, so the best is put in form load

**UPDATE**

To remove the selected index in listbox

```
 Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    End Sub
```

Comment: And I want also to remove Item on listbox or listview if I accidentally selected other item in my combobox,.. is it possible to listview and how to do that? thanks!

Comment: So, you mean every selected, it just only show one line? But your question said will write to new line?

Comment: every selected item in comboBox i want to add it in new line,.. I've tried your code but I used listbox instead of listview and it works fine but I how can I remove Item in listbox?

Comment: you just make a button or on the form load, you write.

Listbox1.items.clear

Comment: I only want to remove only the selected  item on listbox is Used ListBox1.SelectedItem.Clear() then nothings happen the selected item still on the list.

Comment: I have update it, if correct then mark as answer or having any problem. Ask again with proper question clearly

Comment: Ok. Let me give an advice to you for your next time question not been closed or downvote. Before asking a question. Thinking carefully what the exact you want to ask, what have you tried, and what is your problem. Then, said all of them clearly in your question. If your question are complicated and not clearly cause even you are confused of what you wanted to ask. Of course, even we(Stack over flow users) can't help you and will closed your question.

Answer (score 0):

ListView Items can be selected a couple of ways In the Properties window for the ListBox the activation property allows an item to be activated by one click or two clicks. Here is an example of how the selected items can be used

```
    If Me.ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = (1) Then
    'Declare the selected item
     Dim lviSelectedItem As ListViewItem = Me.listView1.SelectedItems(0)
    'Now you can use it
    lblLabel1.Text = lviSelecetedItem.Text

    Else
    lblLabel2.Text = "You can make Items selectable  by switching CheckBoxes property to True in the Properties windows and using CheckBox event handlers"
    End If
```